# Getting Quiet Make to echo command lines on error

Tags: makefile, suppress

I have a Makefile building many C files with long long command lines and we've cleaned up the output by having rules such as:

```
.c${MT}.doj:

        @echo "Compiling $<";\
         $(COMPILER) $(COPTS) -c -o $@ $<
```

Now this is great as the @ suppresses the compilation line being emitted.
But when we get an error, all we get is the error message, no command line.
Can anyone think of a "neat" way to emit the command line?
All I can think of doing is echoing it to a file and have a higher level make catch the error and cat the file. Hacky I know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tested and it worked (GNU make in Linux):

```
.c${MT}.doj:
     @echo "Compiling $<";\
          $(COMPILER) $(COPTS) -c -o $@ $<  \
          || echo "Error in command: $(COMPILER) $(COPTS) -c -o $@ $<" \
          && false
```

Comment: Note that this way make no longer notices that the command failed and will continue as if it succeeded. Maybe you can add a "&& false" to the end to compensate for this.

Comment: I needed to add brackets like:  @echo ... ; compile ... || ( echo ... && false )

Answer (score 7):

This question is pretty old, but for those of you Googling, I think what I’ll do in this situation is alias `make` to `make -s` (silent mode) in my shell, and only put the `@` prefix before lines where `echo` or other diagnostic commands are being invoked.  When I want the full output from `make`, I will override my alias by calling it as `\make`.

Also note that in this situation that you’ll need to do the typical thing and put the `@echo` on its own line, with the actual rule commands on separate lines and without `@`’s.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to use a simple script `abc` like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

$@
code=$?
if (( code )); then
  echo error running $@
fi
exit $code
```

Then you can write `abc $(COMPILER) $(COPTS) -c -o $@ $<` in your `Makefile`. Do note that this does not work when you have pipes or redirects (as they will be applied to `abc` instead of the command you want to run).

You can also just put similar code directly in the `Makefile` if that's preferable.

Answer (score 0):

I recently used a utility called [logtext](http://www.logtext.de/index_en.html) for the likes of tracking what output had occurred during the course of a bat file executing. Check it out, you may find this pretty useful if you want to know what error occurred where.